# How to apply Translate function on all rows within a column in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, translate

In a dataset I have, there is a columns contains numbers like `83.420`, `43.317`, `149.317`, ...  and this columns is stored as string. The dot in the numbers doesn't represent decimal point, i.e., the number `83.420` is basically `83420` etc.
One way to remove this dot from numbers in this column is to use `TRANSLATE` function as follows:

`SELECT translate('83.420', '.', '')`

which returns `83420`. But how I can apply this function on all the rows in the dataset?
I tried this, however, I failed:

`SELECT translate(SELECT num_column FROM my_table, '.', '')`

I face with error `SQL Error [42601]: ERROR: syntax error at end of input`.
Any idea how I can apply translate function on one column in data entirely? or any better idea to use rather than `translate`?

Comment: What’s the purpose of removing the ‘.’? Are you trying  to clean the data, so you will save it back to this , or another, table?

Comment: Why do you tag it as MySql if you are talking about Postgresql??

Comment: @NickW: The purpose is to convert the column into 'INT' using `CAST(num_col AS INT)` then calculate the average of this column.

Comment: @nacho: Sorry! my fault. Just edited it ...

Comment: Why not?: `UPDATE my_table set num_column =  translate(num_col, '.', '')`. Do this in a transaction: `BEGIN; UPDATE my_table set num_column =  translate(num_col, '.', '')` then `COMMIT' or `ROLLBACK` depending on success or failure.

Comment: Since you are working with numbers the better option would be to use `to_number()` from  [Data formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/functions-formatting.html). In particular: `SELECT to_number('83.420', '9999G9999');  83420`. For the template pattern see Table 9.28. Template Patterns for Numeric Formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can even cast the result to numeric like this:

```sql
SELECT translate(num_column, '.', '')::integer from the_table;
-- average:
SELECT avg(translate(num_column, '.', '')::integer from the_table;
```

or use `replace`

```sql
SELECT replace(num_column, '.', '')::integer from the_table;
-- average:
SELECT avg(replace(num_column, '.', '')::integer) from the_table;
```

Please note that storing numbers as formatted text is a (very) bad idea. Use a native numeric type instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two options.

Set up table:

```
create table string_conv(id integer, num_column varchar);
insert into string_conv values (1, 83.420), (2, 43.317), (3, 149.317 );
select * from string_conv ;
 id | num_column 
----+------------
  1 | 83.420
  2 | 43.317
  3 | 149.317
```

First option leave as string field:

```
update string_conv set num_column = translate(num_column, '.', '');
 select * from string_conv ;
 id | num_column 
----+------------
  1 | 83420
  2 | 43317
  3 | 149317
```

The above changes the value format in place. I means though that if new data comes in with the old format, 'XX.XXX', then those values would have to be converted.

Second option convert to integer column:

```
truncate string_conv ;
insert into string_conv values (1, 83.420), (2, 43.317), (3, 149.317 );
alter table string_conv alter COLUMN num_column type integer using translate(num_column, '.', '')::int;
select * from string_conv ;
 id | num_column 
----+------------
  1 |      83420
  2 |      43317
  3 |     149317
\d string_conv 
              Table "public.string_conv"
   Column   |  Type   | Collation | Nullable | Default 
------------+---------+-----------+----------+---------
 id         | integer |           |          | 
 num_column | integer |           |          |
```

This option changes the format of the values and changes the type of the column they are being stored in. The issue is here is that from then on new values would need to be compatible with the new type. This would mean changing the input data from 'XX.XXX' to 'XXXXX'.

Comment: I like your approach as well. If I understood it correctly, with your approach I basically alter the original table, right?

Comment: The second option would do that. The first just changes the format of the values in place.  The issue is how the data is getting into the column. Looks like it is coming from a locale with '.' as thousands separator. In any case a string that is coming in with either '.' or ',' as thousands separator is going to cause an issue on entry into a `numeric` or `integer` field. Ideally the data would come in without the separator.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination!